# Facebook graph api: page posts call returns empty data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Ultimately I am attempting to display a public facebook page feed on the website belonging to the Facebook page's owner.

I am using PHP SDK 4.0 attempting to pull in a couple of posts from the page from graph api v2.2.

I have set up an app on developers.facebook.com, I am using the app id and app secret to setup the default application.

The method I use below to get the access token returns the App access token.

```
// Skip these two lines if you're using Composer
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __ROOT__.'/facebook/src/Facebook/');
require __ROOT__ . '/facebook/autoload.php';

session_start();
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphPage;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

$page_id = "pageID";
$app_id = "appID";
$app_secret = "appSecret";

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( $app_id, $app_secret );

// Get access token
$access_token = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}&grant_type=client_credentials");
$access_token = substr($access_token, strpos($access_token, "=") + 1); 

// Start new session
$session = new FacebookSession("$access_token");


// Get the GraphUser object for the current user:

try {
  $request =  new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', "/{$page_id}/posts");
  $response = $request->execute();
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
  var_dump($graphObject);
} catch (FacebookRequestException $e) {
  echo $e;
  // The Graph API returned an error
} catch (\Exception $e) {
  // Some other error occurred
}
```

Both my code, and typing this information into the URL

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/pageID/feed?access_token=accessToken
```

returns

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Does anyone know why the dataset is empty? 
How can I get the public posts of a page without having to ask the website visitor for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the docs, you know:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/#readperms

> **Permissions**
>
> - An access token is required to view publicly shared posts.
> - A user access token is required to retrieve posts visible to that person.
> - A page access token is required to retrieve any other posts.

This means that an App Access Token is not working. You either need a User or a Page Access Token.

Comment: Does this mean there is no way to display the page posts without asking each website visitor to allow the app access?

Comment: You should also be able to create an eternal Page Access Token and store this in your application. There are plenty of answers here on this topic. Use the search.

Comment: Yes, sure. I would need the username and password of my clients. Or I would have to be added as a manager to their page (headache all on it's own). 

If I ever lose management then the key is lost?

I was looking for a more programmatic way to solve this. I the only other way to seriously ask the visitor if they want to be shown a Facebook stream?

Comment: That's not correct. Facebook OAuth never uses username/password mechanisms. You can query `/me/accounts` with the `manage_pages` permissions for each page owner, and you'll then receive the Page Access Tokens.

Comment: I must be doing it wrong, whenever I attempt to get the page access token for someone else I get an empty data set. Whenever I try to get it for my account, It works, but that does not work for clients that I do not manage their Facebook page.

Comment: Tobi, I believe to do what you are suggesting I do require the user names and passwords of my clients. 
I am unable to query /me/accounts for my clients unless I'm logged into their account and generate the key with the manage_pages permission. 

For the last couple of days I have been researching this and I cannot find any solutions that would allow me to simply present the Facebook stream on the webpage. All solutions seem to want me to ask the website visitor for permission to show them a Facebook stream...

To get the user access token I need to ask their permission.

Comment: Getting the page access_token only works for accounts that I own or am admin for. 

This does not allow me to retrieve my the Facebook page of the website owner I am making the connection for. Again, I can not see a way to do this without me having access to their user name and password :(